Supporting Apple sign-in for mobile and web using dj_rest_auth, allauth
We are looking to implement Apple sign-in from both the web and mobile using this stack.
React SPA using Django 4.2 / DRF 3.15.2 / dj_rest_auth 6.0.0 / allauth 0.61.1 backend
Due to the different Client ID for web and mobile, we had to configure two separate apps in SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS[”apple”] as recommended by allauth. To make this work for the version we are using, we had to manually apply the following patch to 0.61.1 and set the “hidden” property on the mobile app. My impression was that this property is needed to make it work with some admin interface, but maybe not. The explanation is not clear - “For the app specifying the bundle ID, add the following to the settings so that this app does not show up on the web”. We use the same settings for both APPS - secret, key, settings, except for client_id.
When we set this property, the “hidden” app (mobile) never gets used and we get a client_id mismatch error when logging in from mobile. So I guess I am not sure I understand the purpose of having that property. Or maybe we are missing some other patch(es) that make this work.
In short, we can have either web or mobile working at a time, but not both.
The reason why are not using the latest allauth version 64.* is that some serializer change breaks compatibility with dj-rest-auth (issue 639)
Could someone please explain how the multiple APPS setup is supposed to work and the purpose of the “hidden” property? Thanks in advance.
{ "error":"invalid_grant",
  "error_description":"client_id mismatch. The code was not issued to [com.domain.web](http://com.domain.web/).",
  "email_verified":false }

    "apple" : {
        "APPS": [
            {
                "client_id": "com.domain-mobile",
                "secret": "XXXXXXXXX",
                "key": "XXXXXXXXX",
                "settings": { "hidden": True,
                              "certificate_key": """-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----                                                                                                                           
XXXXXXX-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"""
                }
            },
            {
                "client_id": "com.domain.web",
                "secret": "XXXXXXXX",
                "key": "XXXXXXXXX",
                "settings": {
                    "certificate_key": """-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----                                                                                                                                     
XXXXXXXX-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"""
                }
            },
        ]}

